# Storing images in your table's blob yii framework without the use of widget

Tags: php, yii

in my controller I have :

```
$model->attributes=$_POST['Societes'];
                    $file=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'logo');
                    $extension = $file->getExtensionName();
                    $filename = md5_file($file->tempName);
                    $fullFilename = $filename . '.' . $extension;            
                    $model->logo=$fullFilename;
                    if($model->save()) 
                    {                       
                      $file->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath . '/../images/' . $fullFilename);  
                      $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
```

In my view I have :

```
<input type="file" id="id_photo" name="photo">
```

Running this I get this error :

```
Call to a member function getExtensionName() on a non-object
```

Comment: please show us what you have already tried

Answer (score 0):

i thingk these links might help you:

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/how-to-upload-a-file-using-a-model/

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/349/how-to-upload-image-photo-and-path-entry-in-database-with-update-functionality/